# How to correctly use ngProgress after whole DOM is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this module: http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/#demo

Here's my angular controller:

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, ngProgress) { 
    ngProgress.start();
    ngProgress.complete();
}
```

But my load bar finishes after ~1 second. How can i show that loading bar until all DOM (HTML,CSS,SCRIPTS) is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, ngProgress) { 
    ngProgress.start();
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function()
    {
       ngProgress.complete();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it never finishes. Stuck at 98%

Comment: How is your controller and ng-view defined in index.html??

Comment: `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">` i don't have `ng-view` because it's SPA.